# XML Validation vs Java validation

Tags: hibernate, validation

I'm using hibernate validation and am debating which would be a better form of validation for legacy Pojos. Hibernate allows for validation through XML
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html

The new ones can be annotated with constraints which is easier to read. However, for older / generated code that cannot be annotated, putting it in XML does not allow for easy understand of code. I prefer to do the usual Java validations in this case.

Does anyone have preferences? I fXML, I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I use the XML approach because the classes I need to annotate are generated by JAXB. So I'm actually forced to use that approach as I have no source file to annotate with. The XML approach does not look so bad, though the annotation is easier to read.

One advantage I see in the use of XML is being able to centralize all validation information in one file, but you no longer enjoy compile-time checks.